# python Mysql data store

Tags: python, mysql

How to store data in MySQL after receiving it from Python?

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you have provided much information, but here is my shot at an answer. You can use a database library (you can find a list [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiModuleComparison)) to write data to mysql right from you python application.

Comment: ok ! can i send the data from python to be save in MYSql ?! if i can how to do this (  in other word ) code !!

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Select and install the library you want to use to interface with MySQL from the list [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiModuleComparison). Personally I use [MySQLdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/).

Step 2: Use the documentation, online tutorials etc. to attempt to save and retrieve the data. As this is a common task, a Google search shows plenty of examples.

If you have any specific problems doing this, start a new question with a full description of the problem along with any code and error messages.